# Use Lyapunov's method to determine the stability at the origin

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the system 
$x' = y^3 -2x^3$ and 
$y' = -3x - y^3$

I have tried $V(x,y) = ax^4 + by^4$ and ended up getting $ax^4 + 4ax^2y^2 - 2by^6$. I set a=b=1 and got $x^4 + 4x^2y^2 - 2y^6$, but I'm not sure where to go from here. Because it looks like the equation is positive at some times and negative at others.

I am  just learning the Lyapunov method and would appreciate any help.